# Laravel 5 cannot call DB::table() directly outside a class

Tags: php, laravel-5

In my `public/index.php` of a Laravel 5 application, I have to query some fields in my database, so I used `DB::talbe()` to do that.

But it returns error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'DB' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\oceanboost\public\index.php on line 49
```

The code I used to call is:

```
$_active_plugins = DB::table("option")->where("key", "_active_plugins")->first();
```

I tried to use

```
$_active_plugins = \DB::table("option")->where("key", "_active_plugins")->first();
```

but the same error

And here is my full code of `public/index.php`

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels nice to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/
$_active_plugins = DB::table("option")->where("key", "_active_plugins")->first();
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

My question is how to call built-in classes like `DB` in a file when this file is not a class

Comment: Stupid question: did you `use use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB` in the class where you calling the methods from `DB`?

Comment: The problem is not really that the file is not a class but rather that it is *too early* to use the DB facade at that point. Regardless of if it's possible or not it would be wrong to change the index.php like that. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: @Andrew, lukasgeiter: My application have to load plugins before running any other actions. So that I have to query DB at that point. Can you give me any solutions?

Comment: I'd suggest using a middleware on whatever routes need those `active_plugins`. Instead of doing it in index.php do it more laravel-ish.

Comment: @Andrew: I will think about your suggestion. But in my case, how to call DB::table() in index.php which is not a class?

Comment: You don't, that's the whole idea. There's no need. You call it in the middleware, basically you're calling it before any other action is done on that route(that's what middleware is used for). No need to pollute the index with things that are not meant to be there.

Comment: A middleware probably isn't the best fit for this though. I'd recommend creating a service provider instead (see my answer)

Comment: +1 for @lukasgeiter much better than my idea of a middleware. It's a much better idea and works better with laravel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to use the DB facade at that point. The whole database component is booted from the Kernel at this part:

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
```

Before that it's not available.

---

What you *should* do, is create a [Service Provider](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/providers) for that. I won't go into all the details but you basically add a class that has a `register` and an optional `boot` method. You can create one with an artisan command:

```
php artisan make:provider PluginServiceProvider
```

In there you can use the DB facade like you want to. Then you just need to register that provider in `config/app.php` by adding it to the long `providers` array and your code will run before any routing or such happens.

Note that you should put your code into the `boot` method since this one is called after all other providers have been `register`ed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's very useful for me to understand about ServiceProvider.

Answer (score 0):

@Nguyen, if I am not mistaking, I think you are trying to query the database in the `public/index.php`, which is a very big mistake when considering MVC Frameworks.

Please to do this, you should query your database in a controller then pass the results to a view which will be returned to the index.php.

And if you are in a dilemma, see [laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1)

Comment: Yes, I know that. Querying database from `public/index.php` is not recommended. But I have to load all plugins before application is loaded, so that I have to call it directly in index.php